# How to use copyfromrecordset method?

Tags: excel, ado

I can't use copyfromrecordset method when copy to the book

which is not thisworkbook.

the code is as below.

### ---

dim rst

-procedure of set ADODB.recordset to rst-

thisworkbook.sheets("sheet1").range("A1").copyFromRecordset rst
-this works fine. but

workbooks("book1").sheets("sheet1").range("A1").copyFromRecordset rst
-this doesn't work fine.

### ---

How can I let both work fine?

Comment: Are you getting "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" or a different error?

Comment: there are caused no error. but the above sentense displays data,but the below doesn't  at all  for the same recordset (each sentense is exuecuted separately).

Comment: the problem is resolved. I found a error another part. thank you.

Comment: Can you share what the error was? I am having problems with CopyFromRecordset.